# Weblogic coonection pool exahausted

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, weblogic-10.x

We are using weblogic connection pool in application. We are using hibernate for DB access. Now when we try to get connection from weblogic datasource, it throws security exception. So we need to put when weblogic credentials in hibernate.properties as below.

```
hibernate.connection.username=weblogic
hibernate.connection.password=weblogic1
```

Now this works all fine but when I put encrypted password in hibernate.properties and then we decrypt password at start set to hibernate configuration like below

```
String password = config.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"); 
if (password != null) { 
     password = Cryptography.decryptIfNeeded(password); 
     config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",password); 
}
```

Everything works fine, but after while 1 hour or 2 we start geeting weblogic connection pool exhausted issue. Now when I remove the above code to decrypt password and put plain text password in hibernate props everything works fine and no connection pool exhausted isssue even we keep env up for days.

I can not figure out what could be the cause of the issue.
In our application we have a one poller which keeps polling db table after 10 seconds, that poller starts getting connection pool exahsuted error.

PFB stack trace.

```
 -  2014-01-21 00:00:01,104 [Thread-318:WorkProcessor$WorkRunner(WorkProcessor$WorkRunner:D:JobSchedulerDaemon:MAIN)] ERROR (support.context.SessionExecutable) Caught exception from SessionExecutable.execute()
 -  2014-01-21 00:00:01,104 [Thread-318:WorkProcessor$WorkRunner(WorkProcessor$WorkRunner:D:JobSchedulerDaemon:MAIN)] ERROR (batch.scheduler.JobSchedulerDaemon) Exception encountered polling for batch jobs to run
com.splwg.shared.common.LoggedException: 
The following stacked messages were reported as the LoggedException was rethrown: 
com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.createThreadBoundSession(ApplicationContext.java:523): Caught exception from SessionExecutable.execute()

The root LoggedException was: Error creating hibernate session
    at com.splwg.shared.common.LoggedException.wrap(LoggedException.java:198)
    at com.splwg.shared.common.LoggedException.wrap(LoggedException.java:85)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.newHibernateSession(ApplicationContext.java:497)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.initialize(FrameworkSession.java:228)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.<init>(FrameworkSession.java:212)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.createSession(ApplicationContext.java:459)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.createThreadBoundSession(ApplicationContext.java:523)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.SessionExecutable.doInReadOnlySession(SessionExecutable.java:101)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.SessionExecutable.doAsReadOnlyInCurrentSessionIfAvailable(SessionExecutable.java:65)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.SessionExecutable.doAsReadOnlyInCurrentSessionIfAvailable(SessionExecutable.java:57)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.PendingBatchJob.areThereBatchJobsToRun(PendingBatchJob.java:82)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.PendingBatchJob.nextPendingJob(PendingBatchJob.java:38)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.JobSchedulingPollIteration.execute(JobSchedulingPollIteration.java:34)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.JobSchedulerDaemon.performPollingWork(JobSchedulerDaemon.java:80)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.space.PollingDaemon.doExecuteWork(PollingDaemon.java:55)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.JobSchedulerDaemon.doExecuteWork(JobSchedulerDaemon.java:67)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.AbstractGridWork.executeWork(AbstractGridWork.java:69)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.node.WorkProcessor$WorkRunner.runOutsideTransaction(WorkProcessor.java:257)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.space.AbstractTask.run(AbstractTask.java:57)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.space.ThreadPool$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPool.java:166)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74)
    at $Proxy187.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.setNLSDateFormat(ApplicationContext.java:503)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.newHibernateSession(ApplicationContext.java:490)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Internal error: Cannot obtain XAConnection weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resources currently available in pool FCBDataSource to allocate to applications, please increase the size of the pool and retry..
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResourceInternal(ResourcePoolImpl.java:577)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:343)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.reserve(ConnectionPool.java:324)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:94)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getXAConnectionFromPool(DataSource.java:1677)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:446)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.connect(DataSource.java:403)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74)
    at $Proxy187.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.newHibernateSession(ApplicationContext.java:490)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.initialize(FrameworkSession.java:228)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.createSession(ApplicationContext.java:463)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.createThreadBoundSession(ApplicationContext.java:523)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.SessionExecutable.doInReadOnlySession(SessionExecutable.java:101)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.SessionExecutable.doAsReadOnlyInCurrentSessionIfAvailable(SessionExecutable.java:65)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.SessionExecutable.doAsReadOnlyInCurrentSessionIfAvailable(SessionExecutable.java:57)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.PendingBatchJob.areThereBatchJobsToRun(PendingBatchJob.java:82)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.PendingBatchJob.nextPendingJob(PendingBatchJob.java:38)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.JobSchedulingPollIteration.execute(JobSchedulingPollIteration.java:34)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.JobSchedulerDaemon.performPollingWork(JobSchedulerDaemon.java:80)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.space.PollingDaemon.doExecuteWork(PollingDaemon.java:59)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.scheduler.JobSchedulerDaemon.doExecuteWork(JobSchedulerDaemon.java:67)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.AbstractGridWork.executeWork(AbstractGridWork.java:69)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.node.WorkProcessor$WorkRunner.runOutsideTransaction(WorkProcessor.java:257)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.space.AbstractTask.run(AbstractTask.java:57)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.space.ThreadPool$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPool.java:167)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1484)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:446)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.connect(DataSource.java:403)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Please, could you post any relevant database configuration file fragment you have and an example of your code (some simple method you use to query the database)?  Maybe you are forgetting returning your DB resources, or that credentials make me suspect you are opening additional connections to the ones managed by the connection pool.

Comment: I am sure there is no connection leak because, this works with plain text password in hibernate props, this gives only issue with encrypted password.

Comment: But are those credentials to the database you have given to hibernate?  It should never need them if it uses the connection pool, which is itself already identified against the database

Comment: In case of weblogic connection pool access we are providing weblogic credentials not DB bcos weblogic is throwing security exception.